# Send a "zip" file from an Android device to web service Rest

Tags: android

Client :

```
    URL url =new URL("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/wre/zipFile");  // LocalHost  
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/zip");
    conn.setDoInput(true); 
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(50000);
    BufferedOutputStream sout = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream bis = new FileInputStream(zipfile);
    int i;    
    byte bytes[]=new byte[4096]; 
    while((i=bis.read(bytes))!=-1){
    sout.write(bytes,0,i);
    sout.flush();}
    sout.close();
    bis.close();
```

is correct code ?

Server:

what is the server side code?
i.e. download the zip file (d: / zipFile /) and then send to the client by mail
thanks.

Comment: `is correct code ?` Can you test it? Then tell us.

Comment: `what is the server side code?` I must say that i did not expect this question.

Comment: I want code Web Service (java ):  @Path("/zip/")..... ?